# Running a method after the end of the response from serialPort?

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

I am sending a bunch of commands and receiving a response from the serialPort using JSSC Library. At the end of the response, I get three similar responses but with different sequence numbers? like

- l1~cdo~100~1~
- l1~cdo~101~1~
- l1~cdo~102~1~

The pattern is the same every time but the numbers changes. The last message l1~cdo~102~1~ indicates the end of the response and I have to run a method that prints a receipt after the last response. How can I achieve it?

response is a response from the serialport.
is there anyway to capture the last response sequence and create another if statement inside the previous one and compare it like:

```
  if((response.startswith("l1~cdo~")){

//capturing the response and extracting the sequence
    String number = response.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(number);
    builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        if(response.startsWith("l1~cdo~"+builder)){
            serialPort.printReceipt();
        }
  }
```

At this point it will run printReceipt 3 times.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you're having. If `l1~cdo~102~1~` is always the end of a message, shouldn't you just look for that string to indicate that the message is finished?

Comment: The sequence number changes every time. the example I have is 102 but every time I run sequence number change to a random number. it could be 305 or 401.

Comment: Why not counting the responses starting with "l1~cdo~" and printing only after the third

Comment: @FredvN how do I count the responses? I do not get those three responses at once. I get it one after another.

Comment: Somewhere you had to keep track of the received responses. initialise a counter before you receive your first response and after each response starting with "l1~cdo~" increase your counter. When your third response you can print your receipt and probable reset your counter

Comment: @FredvN I got it to work. I initialize the counter as 0 as a global variable.         if ((response.startsWith("l1~cdo~"))) {
                    for (int i = 0; i<1; i++ ){
                        if(response.startsWith("l1~cdo~")){
                            System.out.println(response);
                            counter++;
                            if(counter == 4){
                                serialPort.getReceipt();
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                } Thank you!